# attribute change does not work

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, prettyphoto

I'm working on the prettyphoto image gallery. I need to make a gallery with both "all images" category (containing all image categories) and separate categories of images (containing only images of specific category). To achieve this I'm trying to use jquery to change data-rel attribute of links. The code does not work and I am not able to find out what I'm doing wrong.
Please help, thank you in advance.

javascript:

```
var data_filter = 'category';// value inserted from php
//$('.test').html(data_filter);     
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.cms-isotope-grid-post').each(function(){
      $this = $(this);
      $filter = $this.parent().find('.cms-grid-filter');
      $this.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $this.isotope({
           itemSelector:'.cms-grid-item',
           layoutMode: 'fitRows',
           filter: data_filter
       });
      });
      $filter.find('a').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $filter.find("a").removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var data_filter = $(this).data('filter');
          // my code
          $('.prettyphoto').data('rel', 'all'); 
          // end of my code
          $this.isotope({
              filter: data_filter
          });
      });
   });  
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

php:

```
                                        echo '
                                        <div class="cms-grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 portfolio-'.$image['category'].'">
                                            <div class="portfolio-wrapper muliples">
                                                <div class="entry-content">
                                                    <div class="entry-media cms-blog-media cms-media overlay-wrap">
                                                        <img width="770" height="520" src="photo/'.$image['file'].'" alt="" />
                                                        <div class="overlay">
                                                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                                                <a class="icon circle prettyphoto" data-rel="prettyPhoto['.$image['category'].']" href="photo/'.$image['file'].'">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="entry-header">
                                                    <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="portfolio-detail.php">'.$image['name'].'</a></h4>
                                                    <div class="entry-meta cms-meta">
                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                                                            <li class="detail-terms">
                                                                <a href="#">'.$image['name'].'</a>, <a href="#">'.$image['subtitle'].'</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        ';
```

http://visand.pl/monaco/demo1/portfolio.php

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you mean by 'it does not work'? Does the attribute not change to the value you expect? Does it not change at all? etc

Comment: All the js works except for my line of code.

Comment: The attribute does not change at all.

Comment: I tried also the data() function, it does not work either.

Comment: There are several things wrong in the code you provided. You are assigning values to variables that don't get declared ($this, $filter) and you are searching for classes that you don't have in the HTML you provided ($('.cms-isotope-masonry-post');). Please fix those issues with your code first and come with a more direct question.

Comment: I corrected the code.

Comment: Did you try putting a `console.log($('.prettyphoto').data('rel'));` statement after your line of code, to monitor the value of the `data-rel` attribute, and to confirm that the code is actually executed?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$('.prettyphoto').data('rel', 'newvalue')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it does not work.